# Multiple segues with one custom class for animation in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I have 4 buttons on each side of the screen in MainViewController and 4 different views which are opened by these buttons. I have one class TransitionManager for custom transition animation. In MainViewController I override prepareForSegue and then I use .transitionDelegate to my custom class.

Problem is that i need to animate opening of each view from different sides of the screen. How to use different animation in my class depends on segue.identifier in my TransitionManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions for what you are trying to do. 
You can make different custom classes that inherits from [UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/index.html). 
By example one LeftTransitionDelegate and RightTransitionDelegate.

In your prepareForSegue method you can check the *identifier* of the segue, and use it to choose which TransitionDelegate you want to use.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that